# Why we have to use toBeInTheDocument in Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-dom, testing-library

On the Testing Library documentation on some pages appears this example using screen.getByText:

```
  expect(screen.getByText(/you are home/i)).toBeInTheDocument()
```

[Link](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router)

My question is how is this different from this:

```
  screen.getByText(/you are home/i)
```

Why the documentation is using .toBeInTheDocument() when screen.getByText is doing the same (throws an error when "you are home" text is not in the document)? is it not redundant?.

Comment: Who says you have to use it?

Comment: So why the documentation is using it? What is the benefit?

Comment: In my experience (working with clients), there are plenty of teams which use linting rules that require a `expect(x).method()` statement in every test. As to why they use those rules: my intuition is probably to make it easier to reason about mistakes made in test writing. But (just like you observed) it's unnecessary: if a sync test throws (or an async test rejects), then the test fails. There's no _need_ to use it.

Comment: I just did a bit of additional research for you on this topic, and I'll compose an answer with what I found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It's not necessary**, but some people think it helps communicate intention more clearly.

---

From the blog post [Common mistakes with React Testing Library](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library) (written by Kent, the original contributor):

> ### [Using `get*` variants as assertions](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#using-get-variants-as-assertions)
>
> > Importance: low
>
> ```js
> // ❌
> screen.getByRole('alert', {name: /error/i})
>
> // ✅
> expect(screen.getByRole('alert', {name: /error/i})).toBeInTheDocument()
> ```
>
> This one's not really a big deal actually, but I thought I'd mention it and give my opinion on it. If `get*` queries are unsuccessful in finding the element, they'll throw a really helpful error message that shows you the full DOM structure (with syntax highlighting) which will help you during debugging. Because of this, the assertion could never possibly fail (because the query will throw before the assertion has a chance to).
>
> For this reason, many people skip the assertion. This really is fine honestly, but I personally normally keep the assertion in there just to communicate to readers of the code that it's not just an old query hanging around after a refactor but that I'm explicitly asserting that it exists.
>
> > Advice: If you want to assert that something exists, make that assertion explicit.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to add that beside it being more readable and communicates better, in this case (like most cases) **Explicit is better than Implicit**.

1. If you are not explicit, we kind of relying on the fact that the reader is familiar with the behavior of the method, which is not always the case.
2. If for some reason in the future the behavior changes, this will force us to refactor the code of the test. So by being explicit about it, we are kind of future proofing our test for such cases.