# Check if element does not exist

Tags: typescript, vitest

I have a component that shows a formatted number in a `div`. I can successfully check that the formatted number exists by using

```js
expect(screen.getByText('3.5')).toBeInTheDocument()
```

However, I can't implement the test for not seeing the original number (i.e. 3.51).

I tried for example this:

```js
expect(screen.getByText('3.51')).not.toBeInTheDocument()
```

But I get an error

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: 3.51. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73281448/why-we-have-to-use-tobeinthedocument-in-testing-library

you can check this out.

Comment: @Robiul I'm not sure what part of your link describes the check for non-existence.